# srapy crawl mulitlayer append data in a list and yield this item

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

The web site structure i'm trying to parse using scrapy is the following:

[image: structure]

I'd like the extracted data to have this format:

```
[{
    "project":{"projectname":"project1"},
    "samples":["sample1's_content","sample2's_content","sample3's_content"]
 },
 {
    "project":{"projectname":"project2"},
    "samples":["sample1's_content","samples2's_content","sample3's_content"]
}]
```

I tried this:

```
from item import Item

class Spider(scrapy.scrapy):
    name = spider

    def start_request(self):
        url = "the main page's url"
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parseProjectList)

    def parseProjectList(self, response):
        for url in Selector(Project_list)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parseProject)

    def parseProject(self, response):
        #scrap some data
        myItem = Item()
        myItem['samples']=[]
        myItem['project']={'projectname':projectname,...}
        yield scrapy.Request(url=SampleListPage, callback=self.parseSampleListPage,meta={'myItem':myItem})

    def parseSampleListPage(self, response):
        for url in Selector(Sample_list)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parseSample,meta={'myItem':'myItem'})

    def parseSample(self, response):
        #parse some sample data
        response.meta['myItem'].append(sample_data)
```

I tried to put `yield response.meta['myItem']` at parseSampleListPage

```
def parseSampleListPage(self, response):
        for url in Selector(Sample_list)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parseSample,meta={'myItem':'myItem'})
    yield response.meta['myItem']
```

and also `yield response.meta['myItem']` in parseSample

```
def parseSample(self, response):
    #parse some sample data
    response.meta['myItem'].append(sample_data)
    yield response.meta['myItem']
```

Both solutions failed.

The first one yields empty "samples" fields. The second one creates multiple data with same project like this:

```
[   {
    "project": {
      "projectname": "project2"
    },
    "samples": [
      "sample1's_content"
    ]   },   {
    "project": {
      "projectname": "project2"
    },
    "samples": [
      "sample1's_content",
      "sample2's_content"
    ]   },   {
    "project": {
      "projectname": "project2"
    },
    "samples": [
  "sample1's_content",
  "sample2's_content",
  "sample3's_content"
]   } ]
```

Wonder is there any way to deal with this problem?

Comment: You should add the error message.

Comment: there is no error message, but the data is not what i want, two way i try one is empty, and another one have duplicate data.